# Como forçar um documento html sempre ser aberto pelo navegador?

Tags: java, java-8

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em java para um trabalho em faculdade e tenho uma seção de ajuda para o usuário em que eu abro uma página `html` no navegador, ou pelo menos deve abrir neste.

A questão é que se os arquivos com extensão `.html` estiveram por padrão do sistema para serem abertos por um navegador, tudo bem ele será aberto pelo navegador, porém se esta extensão estiver por padrão vinculada, por exemplo, a um editor de texto ele será aberto no editor de texto revelando o código.

Gostaria de saber se existe um modo em java de um documento `html` somente ser aberto pelo navegador. O código que eu uso é o abaixo:

```
Desktop desktop = null;
desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
URI url = null;

File file = new File("src/ajuda/index.html");

try {

    url = new URI(file.toURI().toString());
    desktop.browse(url);

} catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: E no caso você iria pressupor que o computador tem um programa default? tipo todos tem o IE? nesse caso você poderia usar o Runtime.getRuntime().exec(""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com.br");

Answer (score 3):

Não entendo de java, mas programo em outras linguagens. Não sei aonde está executando seu código, tb não sei se é possível...mas...

E se ao invés de você dar um comando deixando o SO decidir aonde abrir o seu HTML, você chamasse o browser diretamente, passando como parametro o caminho do html, tipo isso:

execute("c:\arquivo programas\ie\iexplorer.exe seuhtml.html").

Isso abrir seu HTML sempre no browser. Se tiver um server rodando na maquina, só chamar o caminho padrão do seu html:

execute("c:\arquivo programas\ie\iexplorer.exe http://localhost/seuhtml.html").

É uma idéia.

Answer (score 2):

Não acho que isso seja possível principalmente porque, fazendo isso, você estaria tirando o poder do usuário de controlar as ações que acontecem no seu próprio computador. Seguindo padrões de usabilidade, o usuário que deve escolher como e com quais programas ele vai abrir/visualizar determinado tipo de arquivo. O que você pode fazer é mostrar mensagens aconselhando a melhor maneira de abrir/visualizar o arquivo;